# Как вместе с nested query выполнить поиск по остальным полям в elasticsearch?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Имеется индекс в эластике

```php
'mappings' => [
    'properties' => [
        'full_name' => ['type' => 'string'],
        'contracts' => [
            'type' => 'nested',
            'properties' => [
                'contract_number' => ['type' => 'text'],
                'id' => ['type' => 'long'],
            ],
        ]
    ]
]
```

При этом выполняется запрос

```php
'query' => [
    'nested' => [
        'path' => 'contracts',
        'query' => [
            'multi_match' => [
                'query'  => $query,
                'type'   => 'most_fields',
                'fields' => [
                    'full_name',
                    'contracts.contract_number',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'inner_hits' => [
            '_source' => true,
            'docvalue_fields' => [
                'contracts'
            ]
        ],
    ],
],
```

затем я извлекаю id нужных договоров для дальнейшего поиска и сортировки в БД

```php
$contract_ids = $root_hits->pluck('inner_hits.contracts.hits.hits')->collapse()->pluck('_source.id')->toArray();
```

По введенному значению contract_number, все находит хорошо contracts.id извлекаются из inner_hits.
По понятным причинам совпадения по 'full_name' не находятся т.к. он и в правду не находится в nested документе.
Конечно была идея добавить в запрос bool.should, но это приведет к тому, что эти данные не попадают в inner_hits, и если сделать парсинг по корневому _source это приведет к проблемам с пагинацией на стороне приложения.

Есть ли решения как в nested query можно добавить к поиску и внешние поля? Может я не вижу просто в документации того, что мне бы подошло в этой ситуации?

Answer (score 0):

Почему-бы не добавить на верхнему уровне `bool`, вынести в него поиск по `full_name`, объединив его с остатками `nested` как два условия в `must`?

Comment: Там пагинация разлетается, если договоров больше одного. Я в принципе так и сделал сейчас.

Comment: В любом случае пагинация будет по записям верхнего уровня. Если вам надо ее выполнять по контрактам, то я бы вместо nested перешел бы на [join field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/parent-join.html), тогда можно было бы искать контракты (children) и фильтровать их по full_name в родителе через [has_parent](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/query-dsl-has-parent-query.html)